# Как пербрать массив и вывести в таблицы?

Tags: php

Есть многомерный массив series в нем данные, я бы хотел эти данные вывести в несколько таблиц разделяя по сезонам и в шапке таблицы написать какой сезон, как это можно сделать? не пойму как надо перебрать массив что бы так сделать

```
[0]['id'=>1,'season'=>1,'series'=>1,'name'=>'1 сезон 1 серия']
[1]['id'=>2,'season'=>1,'series'=>2,'name'=>'1 сезон 2 серия']
[3]['id'=>3,'season'=>1,'series'=>3,'name'=>'1 сезон 3 серия']
[4]['id'=>4,'season'=>1,'series'=>4,'name'=>'1 сезон 4 серия']
[5]['id'=>5,'season'=>2,'series'=>1,'name'=>'2 сезон 1 серия']
[6]['id'=>6,'season'=>2,'series'=>2,'name'=>'2 сезон 2 серия']
[n]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr=[['id'=>1,'season'=>1,'series'=>1,'name'=>'1 сезон 1 серия'],
['id'=>2,'season'=>1,'series'=>2,'name'=>'1 сезон 2 серия'],
['id'=>3,'season'=>1,'series'=>3,'name'=>'1 сезон 3 серия'],
['id'=>4,'season'=>1,'series'=>4,'name'=>'1 сезон 4 серия'],
['id'=>5,'season'=>2,'series'=>1,'name'=>'2 сезон 1 серия'],
['id'=>6,'season'=>2,'series'=>2,'name'=>'2 сезон 2 серия']];

//print_r($arr);


foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    # code...

$vol[$value['season']]='Сезон';

}

echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">';
foreach ($vol as $key1 => $value1) {
    # code...
echo '<th style="width: 150px;" colspan="1">'.$value1.'-'.$key1.'</th>';
foreach ($arr as $key2 => $value2) {
    # code...

if($key1==$value2['season']){

 echo'<tr>';
echo '<td style="width: 150px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.$value2['name'].'</td>';
echo'<tr>';

}

}


}

echo'</table>';
?>
```