# Сортировка новостей на сайте по месяцам в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица со статьями. Статьи имеют формат даты dd.mm.yyyy
Задача создать статистику, с названиями месяцев + каждый год по отдельности.
При нажатии на месяц информации должны сортироваться по соответствующему месяцу.
А если на каком нибудь месяце нет новостей то этот месяц не должен отображаться на списке.
Возможно ли это реализовать в PHP?
см. на рисунок

[image: Пример]

Comment: начните с написания запроса, который вам вернет эти данные

Comment: для начала переделать с использованием нормального формата даты. а по вопросу в целом здесь наверное полсотни готовых ответов на него

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170161/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/1170163#1170163